# Calculating sum of converging series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1-n}{9n^3-n}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series

I have a trouble with calculating the sum of this series:

$$2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1-n}{9n^3-n}$$

I tried to split it into three separate series like this: 
$$2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1-n}{9n^3-n} =2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{3n+1}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3n-1}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n} $$ but I'm not able to continue, can you give me some tips?

Comment: According to WolframAlpha the result is $\frac{\pi}{6 \sqrt 3} + \frac{3 \log(3)}{2}$ so this will take some tricks to work ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's rewrite $\frac{1}{n}$ as $\frac{3}{3n}$, so your sum is $S+2$ with$$\begin{align}S&:=\sum_{n\ge 1}\left(\frac{1}{3n-1}-\frac{3}{3n}+\frac{2}{3n+1}\right)\\&=\sum_{n\ge 1}\int_0^1 x^{3n-2}\left(1-3x+2x^2\right)\mathrm dx\\&=\int_0^1\frac{x-3x^2+2x^3}{1-x^3}\mathrm dx.\end{align}$$Thus $$S+2=\int_0^1\frac{2+3x}{1+x+x^2}\mathrm dx=\frac32\int_0^1\frac{1+2x}{1+x+x^2}\mathrm dx+\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm dx}{1+x+x^2}.$$The rest I'll leave to you.

Comment: Could you explain the first step? Why there is x^(3n-2)? Thank you.

Comment: @aaa Because $\int_0^1 x^{k-1}dx=\frac{1}{k}$.

Comment: nicely done and +1

Answer (score 3):

For the direct evaluation of the limit, you have received the good solution from J.G.

You could also consider the partial sum using, as you did, partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{1-n}{9n^3-n}=\frac{1}{3 n-1}+\frac{2}{3 n+1}-\frac{1}{n}$$ which makes
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac{1-n}{9n^3-n}=\frac{1}{3} \left(\psi \left(p+\frac{2}{3}\right)-\psi
   \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)\right)+\frac{2}{3} \left(\psi
   \left(p+\frac{4}{3}\right)-\psi \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\right)-H_p$$ where appear the digamma function and harmonic number.

Now, using asymptotics and Taylor series you should arrive to
$$S_p=-\left(\gamma +\frac{1}{3}\psi\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)+\frac{2}{3} \psi
  \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{9 p}-\frac{1}{9
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Now, the particular values
$$\psi\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)=-\gamma +\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{3 \log (3)}{2}$$
$$\psi\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)=3-\gamma -\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{3}}-\frac{3 \log (3)}{2}$$ make
$$S_p=\left(-2+\frac{\pi }{6 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{3 \log (3)}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{9
   p}-\frac{1}{9 p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$

For $p=10$, the exact value is $-\frac{477820712081}{12033629407800}\approx -0.039707$ while the above truncated expansion gives $-\frac{199}{100}+\frac{\pi }{6 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{3 \log (3)}{2}\approx -0.039782$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
S &= 2 + \sum_{n\ge1} \frac2{3n+1} + \sum_{n\ge1} \frac1{3n-1} - \sum_{n\ge1} \frac1n \\
&= \sum_{n\ge0} \frac2{3n+1} + \sum_{n\ge1} \frac1{3n-1} - \sum_{n\ge1} \frac3{3n} \\
&= \sum_{n\ge1} \left(\frac2{3n-2} + \frac1{3n-1} - \frac3{3n}\right) \\
&= \sum_{m\ge1} \frac{a_m}m
\end{align*}$$

where the coefficients, defined by

$$a_m = \begin{cases} 2 & m\equiv1\pmod3 \\ 1 & m\equiv2\pmod3 \\ -3 & m\equiv0\pmod3 \end{cases},$$

have the closed form

$$a_{m\ge1} = \frac1{\sqrt3} \sin\left(\frac{2m\pi}3\right) - 3 \cos\left(\frac{2m\pi}3\right).$$

which can be obtained by appropriately combining $\sin\left(\frac{2n\pi}3\right)\in\left\{0,\pm\frac{\sqrt3}2\right\}$ and $\cos\left(\frac{2n\pi}3\right)\in\left\{1,-\frac12\right\}$. (I just borrowed Wolfram|Alpha's "alternate form assuming $n$ is real" from [this result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=SeriesCoefficient%5B%282+%2B+3+z%29%2F%281+%2B+z+%2B+z%5E2%29%2C+%7Bz%2C+0%2C+n%7D%5D).)

Now, recalling that for $|x|<1$,

$$-\log(1-x) = \sum_{n\ge1} \frac{x^n}n,$$

it follows that

$$\begin{align*}
S &= -\frac1{\sqrt3} \Im \log\left(1 - e^{i\frac{2\pi}3}\right) + 3 \Re \log\left(1 - e^{i\frac{2\pi}3}\right) \\
&= -\frac1{\sqrt3} \Im \left[\log\left|1-e^{i\frac{2\pi}3}\right| + i \arg\left(1-e^{i\frac{2\pi}3}\right)\right] \\
&\qquad + 3 \Re \left[\log\left|1-e^{i\frac{2\pi}3}\right| + i \arg\left(1-e^{i\frac{2\pi}3}\right)\right] \\
&= \boxed{\frac\pi{6\sqrt3} + 3 \log\sqrt3}
\end{align*}$$

since $1-e^{i\frac{2\pi}3} = \frac{3-i\sqrt3}2 = \sqrt3 \cdot \frac{\sqrt3-i}2 = \sqrt3 e^{-i\frac\pi6}$.